# Drupal 6 set message to different bootstrap

Tags: drupal, bootstrapping

I'm trying the above code to set a message and redirect to a different location like this
and i'm redirecting from

```
example.com/somewere/index.php
```

to

```
example.com
```

My problem is when i get to example.com drupal doesen't keep the session,
and the message is not shown.

Any idea will be much appreciated.

```
chdir('../'); 
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
require_once './includes/common.inc';
require_once './includes/module.inc';

$url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent'), 'status', TRUE);
drupal_goto($url);
```

i'm taking a form and some other elements of the page and putting it outside drupal in a bootstrap that has session enable.

in 
example.com/somewere/
my message is there

but on example.com/
i dont get the message

the server open me a diffrent session
can it be because i use a diffrent htaccess file in example.com/somewere/

i know messages are session based
is there a way to bypass the problem because there on the same domain and same drupal just different access position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run `session_get_cookie_params` to see whether the path is just `/`. It might be that PHP sets the path to `/somewhere` for the session cookie and so the Drupal install in your install doesnt have a session cookie after that.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to go to these lengths to redirect a Drupal page, something as simple as this in a custom module will do it:

```
function mymodule_init() {
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'index.php') {
    $url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent'), 'status', TRUE);
    drupal_goto($url);
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why you would do this is though, from your message I gather this in response to a form submission? If so you'd be better off setting `$form_state['redirect'] = $url` in a submission handler for the form.

Comment: But why are you trying to put it outside of Drupal? Why not just output a form using a standard Drupal page callback and then call `exit()` so it's displayed immediately? That way you don't have to mess about with bootstrapping Drupal and you can b confident your session will stay intact.

Comment: i'm taking a form and some other elements of the page and putting it outside drupal in a bootstrap that has session enable.

in 
example.com/somewere/
my message is there

but on example.com/
i dont get the message

the server open me a diffrent session
can it be because i use a diffrent htaccess file in example.com/somewere/

i know messages are session based
is there a way to bypass the problem because there on the same domain and same drupal just different access position ?

if no ill manage....
but this will be nice